# Dynamic UITableView height in UIPopoverController (contentSizeForViewInPopover)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have an ipad popover that contains an `UITableView`. After the table is populated, it usually has a few items in it only (4-5), so I'm looking for a way to resize the popover (`contentSizeForViewInPopover`) to the actual table height (the summed height of all its cells).

So, I do have the height but I'm not sure where to call `contentSizeForViewInPopover`, I did try to call it in: `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` but with no success since it seems that the table gets populated later and the actual height is only available later.

Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

EDIT: My cells have different heights based on the content they carry, I can't pre-calculate the height with  `noOfRows * cellHeight`.

Answer (score 18):

I wanted to change the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` when my view appeared to match the `UITableView` and also when I call `reloadData` as I only call this when removing or adding rows or sections.

The following method calculates the correct height and width and sets the `contentSizeForViewInPopover`

```
-(void) reloadViewHeight
{
    float currentTotal = 0;

    //Need to total each section
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfSections]; i++) 
    {
        CGRect sectionRect = [self.tableView rectForSection:i];
        currentTotal += sectionRect.size.height;
    }

    //Set the contentSizeForViewInPopover
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, currentTotal);
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the calculation by doing `CGRectGetMaxY([self.tableView rectForSection:[self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1])` - you only need to know the bottom edge of the last section

Comment: This gives me trouble if I have a UINavigationBar (from a UINavigationController, in the popover). Sometimes it resizing properly, other times it hides the last cell (the height of the navigation bar). It seems to do this when I change the content of my table (cell count changes) and I dont know why or how to fix it.

Comment: When do you call this method?  Is it after reloadData returns?

Answer (score 11):

This answer is courtesy of [@BenLings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41012/ben-lings) from one of the comments above. It's a really clean solution and worth having its own answer:

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover {
    // Currently no way to obtain the width dynamically before viewWillAppear.
    CGFloat width = 200.0; 
    CGRect rect = [self.tableView rectForSection:[self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1];
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);
    return (CGSize){width, height};
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, I had to also incorporate the height of the tables headers or footers if present.

Comment: Where should I call this method?

Answer (score 1):

**Indirect Approach :**

Set your custom height for your UITableViewCell using

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return [indexPath row] * 40;
}
```

Find the total number of rows at a point of your program ... Using the numberOfRowsInSection, get the number of rows.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [self.yourArray count];

//yourArray is the array with which you are populating the tableView
}
```

If you have more than one section, multiple it with the result for the number of rows for the effective number of rows.

Now

```
UITableView Actual Height = Height of UITableViewCell * Total number of rows.
```

**Updated Answer:**

If the cell sizes vary, you might have to do do one of these:

1. Force the text to a smaller size so that all cells have equal height... This can be done using

   'sizeToFit'
2. You will have to find the height of the text using another function. Something like...

   - (float)calculatedHeight {
     return textLabel.frame.origin.ytextLabel.frame.size.height5;
     }
3. You can look at [THIS](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/)  tutorial for resizing UITableViewCell  for variable text.
4. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1525150?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Unfortunately, my cells have different heights based on the content they carry, I can't pre-calculate the height with  `noOfRows * cellHeight`.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this from controller containing a table:

```
- (void)updatePopoverContentSize {
    CGSize size = { CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX };
    size = [self.tableView sizeThatFits: size];
    size.width = 320; // some hard-coded value table doesn't return anything useful for width 
    size.hight = MIN(size.hight, 400); // make sure it is not too big.

    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create an artificial hook, this works well (on iOS 7 at least):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
    size.height = fmaxf(size.height, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
    self.preferredContentSize = size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to get the height is to add the `UITableViewController`'s view with an `alpha` set to `0.0` to the view hierarchy and then get the content size using the `contentSize` property of the table view. This is possible as the table view is a subclass of the scroll view.

Once you have the content size, set the value of `contentSizeForViewInPopover` and then push it onto the popover.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but where should I call `contentSize`? It surely has to be called after the table got populated (aka after - `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`)

Comment: Get it after you've added the invisible table view to the view hierarchy. It should be `addSubview:` followed by `tableView.contentSize`.