# How to set dynamic height of cell based on content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am have an app which requires to display user comments within a table cell. How can I set the dynamic height of the cell based on the contents of the cell like in Instagram?

[image]

Basically, I have texts and comments that have different length in different cells. Can anyone advise me on how I can implement the dynamic height method (like instagram)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check the [UITableViewDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                                heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Bear in mind you can't reference the cell from this method, so you want to calculate the height of the contents separately and use it to generate the height.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advise. I do know of this method, unfortunately I need more advise on how I can calculate this dynamic height?

Comment: It depends on how you're going to draw your cell. If, for example, you were to have a UIImageView coming from an array of UIImages and a UILabel which will display an NSString from an array of NSStrings you'd return 


`[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].size.height + spaceBetweenImageAndLabel + [[stringsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:fontYouWillUseInCell 
                        constrainedToSize:sizeThatIsWidthOfLabelXmaxHeight 
                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeYouWantToUse].height`

Answer (score 3):

Combine my dynamic label category [here](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/how-categories-can-simplify-your-code/) with my dynamic table cell height [here](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/animate-uitableview-cell-height-change/). Perfect combination!

Comment: thanks for the advise! I checked your link for the dynamic label category but was unable to find the info regarding labels. Can you help me on that? As for the dynamic table cell, from my initial understanding, the article states to multiple the cell height by 2 when selected right? Not sure if I missed out on anything, but is there anything on setting the height based on the current set of data to be displayed in the cell?

Comment: Take a look at the UILabel+DynamicHeight... if you call the method + (double)getSizeWithText:(NSString *)text andWidth:(double)width forFont:(UIFont *)font, it returns the height of the cell. Then in the dynamic cell height code, when you return the height of the cell, simply create a version of the cell, set the content and get the size returned.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a look at [three20 library source code](https://github.com/facebook/three20), which offers complex cells like you want to do. It might give you answers on how to do this, even if you do not intend to use it:

[image: three20 Cells]

Comment: Unfortunately this library is no longer supported. Seems to work now (iOS6), but nothing can be said about the future. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to this question. The answer is here.

[Dynamic UITableView height in UIPopoverController (contentSizeForViewInPopover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312821/uitableview-height-after-all-its-cells-are-added/6312861#6312861)