# dynamically increase height of row -iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, height, tablerow

I am having table view.
I want to dynamically increase the height of the row to some size.
How can I do this.
I know its a silly question.But still can't find the solution.Help me please.
I have used this code.But it is not working :

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

 UILabel *lblOutTime = [[UILabel alloc]init];
lblOutTime = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 20, 200, 40)];

lblOutTime.text =@"Outtime : ";

lblOutTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblOutTime.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:5.0f];
lblOutTime.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue Heavy" size:5.0f];

 [cell.contentView insertSubview:lblOutTime atIndex:1];
  return cell;
```

}

Comment: Here I have tried to increase the label height . I am placing label on row (cell).

Comment: In heightForRowatIndexPath calculating the height depending of your content and return the proper value for each cell

Comment: my content is some string value.It will be ok if I will pass some  static height. But what should I do for that?I am having very less knowledge as I am new for iPhone

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345204/objective-c-how-to-set-dynamic-height-of-cell-based-on-content

Comment: @KhushbuShah - you need to implement the method named above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (indexPath.row == myIndexPath)
        {
            return someHeight;
        }
        return  normalHeight;
    } 
In this case the height is not dynamic. here
```

is only 2 fixed positions of cell height. 
as the if conditions shows.

Comment: Want to know how to increase dynamic heights ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can change the size of the cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (indexPath.myRow == myCellIndex)
return NEW_HEIGHT;
else return NORMAL_HEIGHT;

}
```

And you can reload your table whenever you want with:

```
[myTable reloadData];
```

Comment: how can I declare myrow and mycellindex ?Can't get. I am feching some array of strings and displaying them in tableview cell. Sorry if I have asked funny question

Comment: indexPath.myRow is the row of the cell has been pressed, and myCellIndex is a variable you create with the index of the variable yu want to increase.

Answer (score 0):

If You Want Increase the height of all row  use

```
[tableView setRowHeight:44];

[tableView reloadData];
```

if You want increase the height of a particular row use UITableView Delegete `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

and    use this

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

add this tableview delegate method to your class.m file.
Make sure your class conforms to `UITtableViewDelegate` protocol

```
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (indexPath.row == myIndexPath)
        {
            return someHeight;
        }
        return  normalHeight;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row <[ListOfCartItems count])
    {
        CGFloat     result = 44.0f;
        NSString*   text = nil;
        CGFloat     width =220 ;

        clsCart *tempCartPro;
        tempCartPro=[ListOfCartItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        text=tempCartPro.clsProductItem.productName;

        if (text)
        {

            CGSize      textSize = { width, 20000.0f };     // width and height of text area
            CGSize      size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

            size.height += 90.0f;           // top and bottom margin
            result = MAX(size.height, result)  ;    // at least one row
        }

        return result;

    }
    else
    {
        return 230.0;
    }
}
```