# Dynamic textview in dynamic custom cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having some trouble here.

I've got a tableview, with 7 cells, all of them are made using .xib-files. Some of them contain labels, two contain a textview.

The current situation is that all the labels are shown correctly. The height of the cells are the same as the .xib-file states.

The problem is, the textviews are acting up strange. It might have to do something with the fact that I want them to be dynamic. Sometimes, it gives a long story in that textview. Sometimes, only one word. Therefore, the textview should be dynamic, and so should the cell's height be.

The code looks like this:

```
DetLocDescrCell *locDCel = (DetLocDescrCell *)[tabelView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (locDCel == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetLocDescrCell" owner:self options:nil];
    locDCel = detLocDescrCell;
}
[locDCel.locDescrLabel setText:[geselecteerdItem objectForKey:@"LocationDescription"]];
CGRect descrFrame;
descrFrame = locDCel.locDescrLabel.frame;
descrFrame.size.height = [locDCel.locDescrLabel contentSize].height;
locDCel.locDescrLabel.frame = descrFrame;
descrFrame.size.height = descrFrame.size.height + 10;
locDCel.frame = descrFrame;
[listCells addObject:locDCel];
```

This code creates a custom cell from the class `DetLocDescrCell`, loads the data, check whenever the height should be adapted or not, adapts the height, then adds the cell to the list of cells. The list of cells is used again in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. But, the height isn't adapted, and the textviews aren't getting the correct text. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i m not sure whether this is the right way , but i done this way,

The situation is custom cell height & heightforrowatindex cell's height should be same so i tried

calculate the height of textview content in heightforrowatindexpath

```
if(indexpath.row == 3) // containing textview 
{
   CGSize textSize = [txtviewstring sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(190, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 
}
```

then in your cellforrowatindexpath - calculate the same height & initalize height to custom cell textview's height `cell.txtView.frame = CGRectMake (10,10,190,txtsize.height)`.

then both u r txtview height & cell height will be equal

Hope this idea helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to set the height before the cell is drawn on the screen.

Comment: How will setting the cell's height be different from `heightForRowAtIndexPath`? I'll give it a shot.

Comment: By the way, the cell's data is initiated in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Actually, the height is correct (NSLogged it). It's that the height isn't being increased with more text in the textview. That part of the code must be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question. If it is to increase the size of textview on the cell, it is not possible because the cell of the tableview was already created and loaded. It wont go back to the delegate method `tableview:heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` because the indexpath.row will increase when the tableview loads

[Check the tableview delegate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: True that, but I've loaded the data in the `viewDidLoad` method. THe above code comes from that method. Therefore, I'd say the textview's size is altered, but I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: your code will work perfectly for sure. But reloading the tableview `[tableview reloadData]` or again adding the subview after changing the frame `[self.view addSubView:changedLabel]` shows you the result. So make the changes according to this.

Comment: or else use the textview delegate methods like `textViewDidEndEditing:` and `textViewDidChange:` to reload the tableview/textview

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answers in [Dynamic UITableView height in UIPopoverController (contentSizeForViewInPopover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312821/uitableview-height-after-all-its-cells-are-added/6312861#6312861).  Also check out 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1525150?start=0&tstart=0